# Proving a result concerning the size of orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove the following claim:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\alpha :G \to S_n$ a homomorphism. Then the size of every orbit of $\alpha(G)$ (considered as  permutations on n letters) divides $|G|$.

My attempt:

I have the following result

Let $S$ be a group of permutations of a finite set $X$ and $x \in X$. Then the size of the orbit of $x$ is $[S:H_x]$, where $H_x=\{t\in S:t \;fix\; x \}$

So I take $\{1,2,...,n\}=X$ and $\alpha(G)=S$ and if I prove that $|\alpha(G)|$ divides $|G|$ I am done right?

Could yo tell me if I am right? if not Can you help me o fix the mistakes please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $\frac{G}{Ker(\alpha)}\cong \alpha(G)$ and $Im(\alpha)$, is a group. The size of every orbit of $\alpha(G)$, divides $|\alpha(G)|$ and $|\alpha(G)|=|\frac{G}{Ker(\alpha)}|$. Now, $|\frac{G}{Ker(\alpha)}|$ divides $|G|$.